# problem declaring in php for database in xamp

Tags: php

I am learning to use php, html and xamp. what happens is that I have an error because
does not recognize a statement I make on the page to get the list (query) of what you have
the database. the problem is when on the other page it tells me that **empleadoID** is not defined, according to this the **empleadoID** is not defined and i don't know why

here is the list. this is where I define it in the last 2 echo:

```
 <?php
  include("basededatos.php");
  $conexionbd=conectar_bd();
  $query ="SELECT id,nombre,edad FROM empleado;"; 
  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexionbd,$query);
  mysqli_close($conexionbd);
  ?>
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
            <h1>Lista de empleados</h1>
            <ul>
                <?php
                   while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) 
                   {
                    echo '<li>'.$registro['nombre'].' ('.$registro['edad'].'años)';
                    echo '<a href="modificarEmpleado.php?empleadoID ='.$registro['id'].'"> Modificar</a></li>';
                    echo '<a href="eliminarEmpleado.php?empleadoID ='.$registro['id'].'"> Eliminar</a></li>';
                   }
                ?>
            </ul>
  </body>
  </html>
```

This is where he tells me that he doesn't exist:

```
<?php
include("basededatos.php");
$conexionbd = conectar_bd();
$query = "SELECT id,nombre,edad FROM empleado Where id".$_GET['empleadoID']."LIMIT 1";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexionbd,$query);
mysqli_close($conexionbd);
$registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Modificar Empleado</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="actualizarempleado.php" method="post" name="nuevoempleado">
    Nombre: <input type="text" name="empleado_nombre" value="<?php echo $registro['nombre']?>">
    <br>
    <br>
    Edad: <input type="text" name="empleado_edad" value="<?php echo $registro['edad']?>">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="empleado_id" value="<?php echo $registro['id']?>">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="actualizar empleado">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

These are the errors in the second page:

```
 Notice: Undefined index: empleadoID in C:\xampp\htdocs\modificarempleado.php on line 5

 Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\modificarempleado.php on line 8
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133/1839439)

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: "SELECT id,nombre,edad FROM empleado Where id'.$_GET['empleadoID'].'LIMIT 1";

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 major problems. First, you are not using prepared statements. Second, you have a typo error in your SQL query, missing `=`. You can't see the errors because you have not enabled MySQLi errors.

The correct approach would look similar to this

```
<?php
include "basededatos.php";
// This line should go inside conectar_bd()
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conexionbd = conectar_bd();

// prepared -> bind -> execute -> get result
$query = "SELECT id,nombre,edad FROM empleado Where id=? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $conexionbd->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['empleadoID']);
$stmt->execute();
$resultado = $stmt->get_result();

mysqli_close($conexionbd);
$registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
?>
```